# How to open ODP files on Windows XP without having OpenOffice installed

Tags: windows-xp, openoffice, documents

How can I open ODP files on Windows XP if I don't have OpenOffice installed?

Any other programs for that?

Or how can I convert these files to other formats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

conversion always bears the risk of loosing font and text formatting, get **[OpenOffice Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/office/openoffice_portable)**. it's free and can be used from a USB stick and doesn't have to be installed.

open the document in OpenOffice and save it in a format compatible with your word processor.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft Office 2007 SP2 or later can open ODP files with no additional software. [Plugin](http://www.sun.com/software/star/odf_plugin/index.jsp) is available for Microsoft Office 2000, Xp, 2003 and 2007 without SP2.

For a brief list of other ODP supporting software see [wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument#Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument#Software)

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use [this](http://www.sun.com/software/star/odf_plugin) to let MS Office convert them, or an online service like [media-convert](http://media-convert.com/) to transform it into a more usable file format.

Answer (score 1):

[Docx2RTF is free, portable, and compatible with any Windows.](http://www.nativewindsofmontana.com/software/docx2rtf.html)
Converts docx, dotx, sxw, odt to RTF and PDF.